# How to get selected file list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a file upload with progress-bar with the help of HTML5. trying to create multiple file-upload. Below is my code. Inside handleFiles function i have one alert statement and its returning 'undefined'. Can anyone help me here...

```
$('#photoimg').change(function()            
{ 
handleFiles(this.files); alert('got it');
var $fileUpload = $("#photoimg");
if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length)>$('#galCnt').val())
{
    alert("Maximum of 5 images allowed to upload. Only "+$('#galCnt').val()+" left"); 
    return false;
} 

//var formData = new FormData($('#imageform')[0]);
fd = collectFormData();
// Attach the files.
for (var i = 0, ie = PENDING_FILES.length; i < ie; i++) {
    // Collect the other form data.
    fd.append("file", PENDING_FILES[i]);
}

// Inform the back-end that we're doing this over ajax.
fd.append("__ajax", "true");

$("#imageloadstatus").show();
//$("#imageloadbutton").hide();
var $progressBar = $("#progress-bar");
$progressBar.css({"width": "0%"});

var xhr = $.ajax({
    xhr:function() {
        var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (xhrobj.upload) {
            xhrobj.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
                var percent = 0;
                var position = event.loaded || event.position;
                var total    = event.total;
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    percent = Math.ceil(position / total * 100);
                }

                // Set the progress bar.
                $progressBar.css({"width": percent + "%"});
                $progressBar.text(percent + "%");
                $("#loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
            }, false)
        }
        return xhrobj;
    },
    url: SITE_URL+'/index/ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      $progressBar.css({"width": "100%"});
      $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
      $('#preview').html(returndata);
    }
  });
});


var PENDING_FILES = [];

function collectFormData() {
// Go through all the form fields and collect their names/values.
var fd = new FormData();

$("#imageform :input").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name  = $this.attr("name");
    var type  = $this.attr("type") || "";
    var value = $this.val();

    // No name = no care.
    if (name === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    // Skip the file upload box for now.
    if (type === "file") {
        return;
    }

    // Checkboxes? Only add their value if they're checked.
    if (type === "checkbox" || type === "radio") {
        if (!$this.is(":checked")) {
            return;
        }
    }

    fd.append(name, value);
});

return fd;
}


function handleFiles(files) {
    // Add them to the pending files list.
    for (var i = 1; i <= files.length; i++) 
    {
       alert(files[i]);
       PENDING_FILES.push(files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: does input with id `#photoimg` has multiple attribute set, why is `i` set to 1 instead of 0 in the loop in `handleFiles()`

Comment: Yes. The code was working fine. To add progressbar i have meade some changes and now i stuck in HandleFiles function.

Comment: In your `function handleFiles`, shouldn't it start from 0 in the loop?

Comment: @R Lam, Yes.. That's correct :(. I missed it. Thank you. Always i make this kind of simple mistake and spending a lot of time.. :(